# Different log file for different levels in Serilog

Tags: c#, .net, logging, serilog

I am using serilog and I need to save different log levels to different files ( for example debug-20200708.log for debug level, info-20200798.log for debug level and ...)

I used below code but it does not work correctly.

```
var baseLogger = new Serilog.LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Logger(l => l
        .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Fatal))
        .WriteTo.File(
            path: GetLogPath(LogEventLevel.Fatal),
            formatter: formatter)

    .WriteTo.Logger(l => l
        .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Error))
        .WriteTo.File(
            path: GetLogPath(LogEventLevel.Error),
            formatter: formatter)

    .WriteTo.Logger(l => l
        .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Warning))
        .WriteTo.File(
            path: GetLogPath(LogEventLevel.Warning),
            formatter: formatter)

    .WriteTo.Logger(l => l
        .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Information))
        .WriteTo.File(
            path: GetLogPath(LogEventLevel.Information),
            formatter: formatter)

    .WriteTo.Logger(l => l
        .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Debug))
        .WriteTo.File(
            path: GetLogPath(LogEventLevel.Debug),
            formatter: formatter)

    .WriteTo.Logger(l => l
        .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Verbose))
        .WriteTo.File(
            path: GetLogPath(LogEventLevel.Verbose),
            formatter: formatter)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext();

_logger = baseLogger.CreateLogger();
```

Comment: just curious - but why? this is going to make it really hard to follow and costly to generate?

Comment: _"it does not work correctly"_ How? What _does it do_ in contrast to what you expect it to do?

Comment: @Fildor insert all levels to all files

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55376786/multiple-serilog-loggers

Comment: @PeymanMehrabani How could you solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason it doesn't work is because you're not using the `.WriteTo` of the filter, and instead you're using the `.WriteTo` of the main pipeline (which doesn't have filters applied).

E.g. Instead of:

```
.WriteTo.Logger(l => l
    .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Fatal))
.WriteTo.File(
    path: GetLogPath(LogEventLevel.Fatal),
    formatter: formatter)
```

You need (notice the difference in parentheses):

```
.WriteTo.Logger(l => l
    .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Fatal)
    .WriteTo.File(
        path: GetLogPath(LogEventLevel.Fatal),
        formatter: formatter))
```

This applies for each of the `.WriteTo` calls you have as they all have the same issue.

Once you fix that, you'll see that the logs are written to the corresponding files now, except for `Verbose` and `Debug` (files are empty). The reason for that is because Serilog's default `MinimumLevel` is `Information` so anything lower than that is ignored. To resolve that you need to set the `MinimumLevel` to `Verbose` in the logging pipeline configuration:

```
var baseLogger = new Serilog.LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
    .WriteTo.Logger(l => l
    // ...
```

---

ps: There's also a different approach to doing what you're doing using the [Serilog.Sinks.Map](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-map) sink which you can see an [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62069498/211672).

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue for inserting in SQLServer in different tables. I solved it by doing this

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
.WriteTo.Conditional(x => x.Level == Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Error, conf => conf.MSSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LogConnectionString"),
    new SinkOptions { AutoCreateSqlTable = true, TableName = "Error" }))
.WriteTo.Conditional(x => x.Level == Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Warning, conf => conf.MSSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LogConnectionString"),
   new SinkOptions { AutoCreateSqlTable = true, TableName = "Warning" }))
.WriteTo.Conditional(x => x.Level == Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Debug, conf => conf.MSSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LogConnectionString"),
    new SinkOptions { AutoCreateSqlTable = true, TableName = "Debug" }))
.WriteTo.Conditional(x => x.Level == Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information, conf => conf.MSSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LogConnectionString"),
    new SinkOptions { AutoCreateSqlTable = true, TableName = "Information" }))
.WriteTo.Conditional(x => x.Level == Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Verbose, conf => conf.MSSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LogConnectionString"),
   new SinkOptions { AutoCreateSqlTable = true, TableName = "Verbose" }))
.CreateLogger();
```