# Converting Log4Net to Serilog

Tags: log4net, serilog

Log4Net can have many loggers, and I wounder how I can do the same with Serilog.
I read about writing to different files depending on log level or a filter expression, but did not found anything about using different log names.

```
public class Logger
{
    public static ILog Log
    {
        get
        {
            return LogManager.GetLogger("DomainLog");
        }
    }

    public static ILog LogUltimo
    {
        get
        {
            return LogManager.GetLogger("UtlimoDomainLog");
        }
    }

    public static ILog CriticalErrorLog
    {
        get
        {
            return LogManager.GetLogger("CriticalBusinessErrorLog");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the xml configuration:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>

<logger name="DomainLog">
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="DomainLogAppender"/>
</logger>

<appender name="DomainLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="Logs\DomainLog.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="50" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%d [%t]%-5p- %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="UtlimoDomainLog">
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="UtlimoDomainLogAppender"/>
</logger>

<appender name="UtlimoDomainLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="Logs\DomainLog.ultimo.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="50" />
    <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%d [%t]%-5p- %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="CriticalBusinessErrorLog">
    <level value="ALL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CriticalBusinessErrorLogAppender"/>
</logger>

<appender name="CriticalBusinessErrorLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="Logs\CriticalBusinessError.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%d [%t]%-5p- %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="NHibernate.SQL">
    <level value="ALL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="NHibernateAppender"/>
</logger>

<appender name="NHibernateAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="Logs\NHibernate.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%d [%t]%-5p- %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

</log4net>
```

Answer (score 3):

The usual ways of having separate loggers with Serilog are either with [sub-loggers](http://nblumhardt.com/2016/07/serilog-2-write-to-logger/) using [filters](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics#filters) or via [Serilog.Sinks.Map](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-map), using [context properties](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment#the-logcontext) to decide which logger will include or exclude certain messages.

You can see more detailed answers and examples on these other questions here on SO:

- [Serilog : choose which sink to log at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65632945/211672)
- [Different log file for different levels in Serilog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65348118/211672)

---

That said, nowadays it's common to have all the logs be sent to a central logging server that you can filter, map correlations, etc. and instead of separate logs, you would "tag" log messages with different [SourceContext](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65631652/211672)s (or a different property that you name/know about) which would allow you to easily filter the logs in the central server.

You might want to look at [Exceptionless](https://github.com/exceptionless/Exceptionless), [Seq](https://datalust.co/seq), [Sentry](https://sentry.io), and similar.

Comment: Thanks, very good answer. Our goal is to log to EleaticSearch I havde don that on other projects. But right now I am trying to move all projects to Serilog and prepare it for ElasticSearch